# How to check if two different LINQ queries has same result?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression

The blow two different queries evaluate to same result.
I need to check the equality of these without executing the query.
How to check if two different LINQ queries are the same ?

```
var exprA = (from o in orders where o.HasPrice == true);
var exprB = (from o in orders where o.HasPrice != false);
//HasPrice is a boolean
```

Any build in .NET solution or existing library would be appreciated.

Comment: Just curious: What is the context, why do you need to know, if that code is basically doing the same?

Comment: @Udontknow Performance issues. It won't be always a boolean. It might be `where o.Price > 0 && o.Price < 2` and `where o.Price == 1` where Price is int. Please check Backs answer to this question.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for:
1, Whether the final result IEnumerbale<T> of above two queries is same
or 2. You do not even want to go to the level of generating the IEnumerable type and want to you the equality beforehand. In case 1 we can simply create an IEnumerable comparer by overriding the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the type T. I can provide a solution is its case 1

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I have mentioned don't want to execute query. This mean it's case 2 in your comment.

Comment: @Mahdi this is ideally not a Linq question, you are looking for a semantic search and compare solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these two (or any other two) statements are "the same" is very poorly defined. What if HasPrice is ***not*** a bool as one would expect?

In any case, the closest thing to an answer here would be that you need to use a [SMT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) to evaluate that. I don't know that one exists "out-of-the-box" for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I think, it'e nearly to impossible solve this problem. Because, in complex queries there are complex conditions like:
`where o.Price > 0 && o.Price < 2`
and
`where o.Price == 1`.
Sometimes these queries are equal (when `o.Price` is int or long), but sometimes are no (when `o.Price` is double, for example).
So, in common way it can not be solved. Borders of problem are very undefined.

It seems to me, that your question is not a original problem, it's part of solution. So, maybe we need go deeper to see initial problem.